# Getting rollback in creating shortcuts on installation of node js in windows 7

Tags: node.js, installation

I'm trying to install nodejs server on my Windows 7 machine. I've downloaded the latest version of node (node-v0.8.11-x64.msi) from the official site and tried to install it.

When the process reaches "Creating of shortcuts " I'm getting rollback installation with an error.

Does anybody has the same problem?

Comment: What is the exact error that you're getting?

Answer (score 4):

I simply removed the option of "creating shortcut to online documentation" during the installation. :)

Answer (score 0):

The source of the error can vary, the best method to detect is to create a [verbose log of the installation](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/223300). Once you have that you can search for "**value 3**", usually this string appears when a standard/custom action fails during the install.

Answer (score 0):

These two steps fixed the problem for me.

1. Copy the msi to a local directory on your hard drive.  Your “downloads” folder may be on a network share in a roaming active directory environment so it is not really local. (I believe this true local copy of the msi is important as it seems to re-establish the owner chain of the msi file as belonging to you, not the internet.)
2. Open an administrative command prompt.  Change to the directory that you copied the msi to and then run the file.   (Similar to C:\LocalDir>**node-v0.10.35-x64.msi** )

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

> msiexec /i node-v0.12.0-x86.msi /passive ADDLOCAL=ALL REMOVE=Docume
>   ntationShortcuts ALLUSERS=1