# Rollback on node.js install on Windows 7 x64 PC

Tags: node.js, windows-7, 64-bit

I've been trying to get node.js installed on my home PC for a while now with no luck. I've tried different versions for the past couple months and no matter what I try it starts rolling back the install at "Creating shortcuts" and it fails to install. I created an install log for anyone who wants to look at it and take a stab at helping me solve the problem. Thanks!

https://dl.dropbox.com/u/177486/MSIf99e3.LOG

Comment: As per StackOverflow guidelines, please **embed** all information relevant to the question.  It is fine to *also* include a link, as long as the question itself is self contained without needing to click. If the link were to become unavailable, this page/question/answers would become useless, downgrading the efficacy of SO.  Also, user experience suffers when users are required click around the net just to find out what the question (or answer) is.  Thanks.

Comment: The link is now unavailable, which makes the question somewhat worthless as we can't see what the error was.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Windows Installer is reporting that it's installed even though it's been rolled back.

Run `msiexec /x {29552F29-7FE9-441F-BC56-E6B591587A59}`

Where the above guid is the `ProductCode` value from your log.

If that doesn't work and you have access to Orca.exe from the Windows SDK, you may be able to modify `WixSchedInternetShortcuts` to a false condition and install successfully. To do that, install Orca, then right click on the node.js msi file and choose 'Edit with Orca' then:

1. Highlight `InstallExecuteSequence` under "Tables" on the left.
2. Find `WixSchedInternetShortcuts` in the right
3. Double-click the Condition cell and change `VersionNT > 400` to `0`
4. Go to File -> Save
5. Run the installer again

After installing this version, you should be able to cleanly remove it via Add/remove programs and install another version without modifying the msi file.

Comment: first suggestion didn't work, gonna try the second suggestion here once I get Orca installed.

Comment: second method worked, I installed it after editing it, and then did a remove from add/remove and tried an unmodified installer but the unmodified did the same thing it was doing so I just used the modified installer to install it and will deal with it. Thanks.

Comment: No problem. I tried 0.8.12 and 0.8.13 in Windows 7 x64 and Windows 8 x64, both of which worked. It could be a permissions thing preventing the installer from writing to your AppData folder.

Answer (score 12):

I have faced the same problem, I have resolved my issue. I just mark `performance counter` to **Install when required** during **installation of node.js**
[image]

Comment: Fought for hours trying to get the darn 4.2.2 to install (what we need for our enviro...this answer worked.  I was missing the binding for 4.2.2 after, so ran 'code' npm rebuild node-sass --force

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem with v0.10.35. (23 Jan 2015)

All I had to do was disable the shortcuts in the custom install pane and it worked fine:

[image: custom image pane with disabled shortcut option]

Answer (score 2):

My solution
You must install each item separately.

1. Npm package manager
2. Add to path
3. Online documentation ...
4. Nodejs runtime / Performans counter
5. (İmportant) nodejs runtime / Event tracing(etw) (select"feature will be installed be required"
6. restart computer

[Last install view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hfjSD.png)

Comment: I tried all the other variants and this is the one I had to use!  Win 10 x64 - brand new PC build May 2018, maybe reason as NPM not up to date yet with patches etc.

Answer (score 1):

**All above methods do not work.**

> -running msiexec as admin
>
> -msiexec /x ...
>
> -modifying WixSchedInternetShortcuts
>
> -dropping the row WixSchedInternetShortcuts
>
> -even this: [removing the option of creating shortcut to online documentation during the installation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16232615)

[Might manually fix it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12567371/861273), you can read [this help](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/disable-rollback-feature-windows) to install product and then [add](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm) `C:\Program Files\nodejs` Path to Windows Environment variables.

Answer (score 1):

Open the command promt and paste the below comman

> reg query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Perflib_V2Providers{793c9b44-3d6b-4f57-b5d7-4ff80adcf9a2}" /s
>
> reg query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Perflib_V2Providers{1e2e15d7-3760-470e-8699-b9db5248edd5}" /s

If you get a result for the command , go to the registry key and delete that key. Now try to install it again. You should be able to install it now.

Answer (score 1):

```
msiexec /i node.msi /qn+ ADDLOCAL=ALL REMOVE=NodePerfCtrSupport,NodeEtwSupport
```

This might help

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem. Solution 1 provided by Jim Schubert did not fix it. I then used Orca to edit the installation file. Changing the `VersionNT` condition also did not fix it for me. I then just dropped the rows from `WixSchedInternetShortcuts` and it installed successfully. I guess it had some problem with writing the shortcuts. I had also previously tried running msiexec as admin ("/a" option), but this didn't fix it...

Answer (score 0):

One point to be aware of (I learn it the hard way): even after having edited the installer with Orca, don't try to uncheck the checkboxes for shortcuts creation in the installer, leave them checked or it will fail with the same error message.

Answer (score 0):

It happened to me as well, I removed almost everything from the installation and completed the installation. After that I ran the installation again and added one by one until I installed all.

Answer (score 0):

You can always use chocolately install:

https://chocolatey.org/packages/nodejs.install/8.11.1

```
choco install nodejs.install --version 8.11.1
```

Answer (score 0):

- Check if Avast Antivirus is installed in your machine.
- If it is turn off the shields and try installing nodejs

Now it works completely fine...